# How to use parent of a directory in a Source parameter of the Files section?

Tags: inno-setup

I can't for the life of me figure out how to point to the parent of the source directory in the `[Files]` section.

Here is an example of what I need:

```
[Files]
Source: "{parentofsrc}\Documentation\\*";` 
DestDir: "{pf}\MyProgram\"; Flags: external`
```

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you might be able to use "..\{src}\Documentation\". If it works, I'll write up an answer that explains it.

Comment: I tried "..\{src}\Documentation\" and it just put the full path of {src} in there so I get something like "..\C:\Program Files\MyProgram\Documentation". So that solution doesn't seem to work.

Comment: OK. Try this "{src}\..\Documentation\" instead.

Comment: I wrote the answer that explains how it works, so that future readers will understand what's being done here. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `"{src}\..\Documentation\"`.

The `..` notation means "the parent of the current folder, so in the snippet above it means "starting in the `{src}` folder, move up one leve (the parent of `{src}`), and then down into the `Documentation` folder there.

Comment: For some reason Inno Setup doesn't interpret .. as such for me, but instead just straight up puts it in the path as-is. The {src] also does not get resolved. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: @Schred: Did you mean to type `{src}` (note the paired curly brackets) rather than the `{src]` (note the typo in the right curly bracket - you used a square one)? If so, is that also the issue in your script? I can't tell you why it's not working for you (other than that possibility), because I can't see your script. The typo is the only reason I can see for why `{src}` wouldn't be expanded.

Comment: Yes that was a typo in the comment, sorry about that. Posting my script here makes no sense of course; I might just have to open a new question, as I can't find anything on the matter online.

Comment: Alright, I figured out what to do now. You can only use .. if you specify the external flag, but that means the files will be missing when you actually execute the installer unless you ship them as well, which is the complete opposite of what you're trying to do. Instead I now simply move the directories I need into the folder of my script file.