# InnoSetup [Files] section source in another directory

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to jump up a few directories when setting the `[Files]` source setting?

Such as:

`[Files]
Source: "..\..\updateScript.sql"; DestDir: {tmp}; Flags: deleteafterinstall;`

Comment: This might be related, but a quick attempt to use this approach wasn't fruitful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072482/how-to-use-parent-of-a-directory-in-a-source-parameter-of-the-files-section?rq=1

Comment: Based on what I have above, what should I change to be able to jump up a few directories and grab a file?

Comment: Example: 
I have my script in `C:\My IS Scripts` and I want to take file from `C:\Sources\MySuperAppSources\Assets\DLLs`: `Source: "..\Sources\MySuperAppSources\Assets\DLLs\FileIWantToGrab.DLL"` - so in general your example is OK, but maybe you have added one `..\\` to much or something like that.

Comment: Your current entry expects the `updateScript.sql` file two directories up in the level from where you have your ISS script. But the usage is correct...